# Why SUM() returns NULL when no row is selected?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))) as num_day
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = :id
```

`SUM()` return `NULL` when now row is selected. I mean when `:id` isn't exist in the `mytable`, the result of `num_day` is `NULL`.
Based on my needs, it shouldn't be `NULL` at all. It should be `0` or more.

Anyway, How can I calculate the number of being-true of a condition? Here is the condition:

```
date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))
```

Comment: "Why is it `NULL`?" – Because *the sum of an empty set* is undefined and/or nonsensical.

Comment: @deceze Ok what's the best way to get `0` instead of `null` in that case ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to wrap it with a `ifnull()` to return a `0` in the case of `null`

```
 ifnull( sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))), 0)
```

Comment: Yes or `COALESCE()`. But actually I want to know, can I do that by `count()` instead of `sum()`?

Comment: Yep, look at answer from @bukko

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_day
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = :id
AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))
```

SUM() will return null if there is nothing to add up.
COUNT will return the actual number, or 0 if none.

Comment: This is a very good solution.  The query can take advantage of an index on `mytable(user_id, date_time)`.

Comment: Well here is [my query](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b2b48e8f6ea7dd2a6e7e53e521f0b29) in reality, Can I write that like what you suggested?

Comment: Are you sure that query is right? You have the same calculation for `day`, `hour` and `1min`

Comment: @bukko Yes I'm pretty sure that's correct. Also no, the calculations aren't identical. Because of `INTERVAL 1  day` and `INTERVAL 1  hour` and `INTERVAL 1 minute`.

Comment: Ah ok I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I calculate the number of being-true of a condition? Here is the condition:

Use `CASE` inside the conditional `SUM`

```
SELECT sum( CASE WHEN date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), 
                                                          INTERVAL 1  day))
                      THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END
          ) as num_day
```

Comment: Still it returns `NULL` when no row selected.

Comment: I guess you have to use that `CASE` outside the `SUM()`.

Comment: Nope in that case you have to add `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`, The difference between this and @bukko solution is .... if you need different conditional `COUNT(*)`  you can't put it on the `WHERE` ... For example `SUM(month=january), SUM(month=february)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(if(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))),1,0) as num_day
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = :id
```

Use query like this.

Comment: I am answering from mobile so don't have dormat options, can you please, i will approve edit.

Comment: It still returns `NULL` when nor row is selected.

Comment: Yes my mistake in query SELECT sum(if(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day)),1,0)) as num_day
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = :id